# Assign Text Node to data-title

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I'm sure this is probably an easy one.
I need to assign a text node to a data-title attribute using javascript

So I need this....

```
<div class="error">text</div>
```

To return this....

```
<div data-title="text" class="error">text</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.error').setAttribute('data-title', document.querySelector('.error').textContent)
```